# Possible to create a double outline for number with css?

Tags: css, outline

Is it possible to create a double outline for number how you see in below picture (I mean the green and white outline)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want this for **_any_** numeric character in the body-text, or is the number inside a container (div, span, etc.)?

Comment: I need for ANY numeric and text character @Lars Kristensen. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, it's not the exact same effect, but you could achieve something similar with a combination of text-shadow and -webkit-text-stroke.

```
   text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 green;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/rs27av43/4/

Here is another (perhaps better) option using `::before` and `custom data attributes` - props to the *Code Carnivore* for this intelligent solution)

https://jsfiddle.net/0wn2ok4g/2/

Comment: Yes exactly. I was also trying with that combination. Thanks @Brian FitzGerald

Comment: It will be hard from the responsive point as when making font sizes small all looks ugly

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. I think you should possibly use some extra classes for that... like `.very-small-text-outline` `.small-text-outline` `.medium-text-outline` `.large-text-outline` and adjust your stroke and text-shadow widths based on that, and then dynamically apply the classes based on the text size you need.

Comment: Yeah exactly. thank you very much for the answer and example @Brian FitzGerald

Comment: Ok man, added one more option using `::before` and `custom data attributes` after discussing this with a coworker. Extreme programming always yields the best results! Good luck with the implementation.

Comment: Yeah great solution @Brian FitzGerald. If i could would vote up your answer again!)

Answer (score 3):

You can play with text-shadow.
It looks not cool, but I think this is all you can do with css.

Original [article](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) on CSSTricks.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

span {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: block;
  
  text-shadow:
     -2px -2px 0 green,  
      2px -2px 0 green,
      -2px 2px 0 green,
       2px 2px 0 green,
     -3px -3px 0 white,  
      3px -3px 0 white,
      -3px 3px 0 white,
       3px 3px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
```

Comment: Hmm good idea but when making numbers smaller all crushes, i need some responsive solution @3rdthemagical

Comment: @AnahitDEV For small font-sizes you can decrease the size of text-shadow from 2px to 1px and from 3px to 2px. Or you can use only outer shadow. That's all I can recommend.